# LWP::UserAgent get(): is there a default size for the `read_size_hint` option

Tags: perl, size, lwp-useragent

When using the `get` method from [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) with `:content_file` and `:content_cb` set but without setting `:read_size_hint`: will there be a constant default value or could the chunk-size change?

Comment: What happens when you read the source? It's there for you to see, and although I could answer this question be looking, I wouldn't want to deprive you of that fun. :)

Comment: I tried to read the size of the chunks and it seems to me that the first 4 chunks and possibly the last differ from the rest of chunks which are all equal.

Comment: It differs from the sort of download - sometimes the chunks are all equal (excluding the last).

Comment: It's normal for the last one to be smaller. Let's say you have to download a file of 18KB and the size of the chunk is 4KB. First 4 chunks will be equal, ant the last one will be 2KB: 18KB = 4 x 4KB + 2KB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in LWP::Protocol::http (LWP::Protocol version 6.00): the default chunk size is 4096 bytes.